# Trying to reproduce the same predefined uppercase function using custom pipe ---> Getting this error in console

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML template example using the pipe:

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="titleCasing" (keyup.enter)="titleCasingFun()" />

<span>{{ titleCasing | titleCasingtransform }}</span>
```

Custom `Pipe` implementation:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'titleCasingtransform' })
export class TitlecasingPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(titleCasing: string) {
    return titleCasing.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

Getting Below Error

> core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Comment: Update this line: `return titleCasing.toUpperCase();` to `return titleCasing && titleCasing.toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly said that `titleCasing` is undefined. Very simple way is to use `Optional chaining (?.)` that introduced in [typescript-3-7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html):

```
export class TitlecasingPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(titleCasing: string) {
    return titleCasing?.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see only one `toUpperCase` call. That means `titleCasing` is undefined. To deal with it one can do the check for `undefined`. A possible solution would be:

```js
transform(titleCasing: string) {
  return titleCasing && titleCasing.toUpperCase();
}
```

While in general, one can not be sure that pipe would receive a string as an argument for the transform pipe. For production-ready reusable pipe, it would be wise to handle such cases. A possible solution would be to throw an exception if the argument is not a string.

```js
transform(titleCasing: any) {
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    throw invalidPipeArgumentError(LowerCasePipe, value);
  }
  return titleCasing && titleCasing.toUpperCase();
}
```

or convert argument to a string:

```js
transform(titleCasing: any) {
  return titleCasing && `${titleCasing}`.toUpperCase();
}
```

Which might handle `false` unexpectedly and some other edge cases. It might not be worth the coding to handle edge cases for your project. So, it's up to you to decide on it.